# Permission Denied (Public Key) EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'd like to ask you for assistance on this. It is the first time I'm trying
to ssh into EC2 instance from my laptop. I've got `pem` file with permission bits set to 400 in `~/.ssh`

The instance is up and running and my attempt is:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/app-prod.pem coding_hedgehog@ec2-1-7-6-51.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

output:

`coding_hedgehog@ec2-1-7-6-51.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey)`

I'm following [this](https://99robots.com/how-to-fix-permission-error-ssh-amazon-ec2-instance/) article but nothing seems to work in my case. `coding_hedgehog` is my IAM and it is displayed when I'm logged into AWS console so the problem can't be using wrong IAM nick.

The EC2 instance runs Ubuntu 20.04

Some tutorials show that using `ubuntu@public_dns` will work. I get the same error though.

Security Group inbound rules:

[image]

Instructions to connect via ssh:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to go on EC2 Console Select your Instance and there will be option name **Connect**. It will show you how to connect your instance using SSH.

Comment: One more thing it's not good to reveal your Instance DNS in question, you should mask that. Stop your Instance and again start it. It will Change your Public DNS of your Machine.

Comment: @AchyutVyas  If you try to use the dns it will show you invalid.  :)

Comment: Are you sure that `~/.ssh/app-prod.pem` is the correct key associated with your instance?

Comment: @AchyutVyas  Tried to click on Connect and followed the steps. Pretty straightforward. No rocket science. Still throws "Permission Error".

Comment: @Mark ~/.ssh/app-prod.pem is probably the wrong key.

Comment: @AchyutVyas I'm gonna generate new key as I don't wanna spend all day on ssh keys.

Comment: @AchyutVyas  Does the `-i` flag should include path to the key as well or is does it look in `~/.ssh` automatically ? Even after generating new key and giving it permission table of 400 I still get "Permission Denied (Public Key)"

Comment: `-i` suggest that you are connecting your instance using a private key. I suggest you to use Full path of your .pem file. `~` stands for your users' home directory.
Ex. If your .pem file is located at **/home/mark/.ssh/app-prod.pem** and you are logged in as **mark** user then you can use key path as **~/.ssh/app-prod.pem**

Comment: Roger that. In this particular problem there are only few things that can cause a permission problem and I've covered them all. I'm using `-i ~/.ssh/app-prod.pem` as all ssh keys are stored there by default.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure that Security Group can cause permission denied issue, have you tried to connect your instance with another system?

Comment: Up until now I've been using docker machine to interact with the instance but ever since I started to need using storage with greater capacity I could no longer create the instance with `docker-machine create` command (it's a known bug). So I'm forced to ssh into the instance and install Docker manually.

Comment: @AchyutVyas  Security Group can indeed cause the issue if you don't expose inbound port 22. But mine is exposed. I checked.

Comment: @MArk I'm Confused about `coding_hedgehog` you said it's IAM User name, IAM user's are maintained by Root Account of AWS, but your Username of EC2 instance must be ubuntu (as it is Ubuntu 20.04, that depends on AMI) can you edit your question with instruction written in **Connect** guide of EC2 console?(Mask your public DNS)

Comment: @AchyutVyas  Added to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224795/discussion-between-achyut-vyas-and-mark).